# Implementation of Levenshtein on database records using python

Tags: python, similarity, levenshtein-distance

How do I implement levenshtein distance on records in a database table using python? I know how to connect python with database, coding in python may not be problem, and I also have the records in a database table. I understand the theory and the dynamic programming of levenshtein distance. The problem here is, how do I write the codes in such a way that after connecting to the database table, I can compare two records having up to three fields and output their similarity score. Below is a snipet of my database table:

Record 1:
Author : Michael I James
Title :  Advancement in networking
Journal: ACM

Record 2:
Author: Michael J Inse
Title: Advancement in networking
Journal: ACM

Any ideas is welcome. I'm a newbie in this area, please try explain with a little detail.
Thanks.

Comment: some databases provide working `levenshtein()` function, for example [PostgreSQL fuzzystrmatch module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)

Comment: @Korylprince, thanks for your response.I have been able to access and query the database records from python.
I have looked at several codes written in python for computing levenshtein distance.
What I do not know is how to apply the code on the records and get the similarity scores..
The records are over 20,000 in number
I also intend downloading python-levenshtein distance C extension which I learnt is faster and easier to implement.

Comment: @Tiger1 this site is more for questions about specific code problems you are having. Try using that module and get some code going. If you have problem with specific code you should post then.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of you problem is that you do need to identify very similar records which are potentially duplicated.
I would solve this in the database itself. No need to do programming. If you don't have the Levenshtein function available in your DB you may want to create a User Defined Function.

Here is an example for MySQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `levenshtein`(s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS int(11) DETERMINISTIC  
BEGIN    
  DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT;
  DECLARE s1_char CHAR;    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256);
  SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0;
  IF s1 = s2 THEN 
    RETURN 0;
  ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
    RETURN s2_len;
  ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
    RETURN s1_len;
  ELSE 
    WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
      SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
    END WHILE; 
    WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
      SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET c = c + 1; 
        IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN 
          SET cost = 0; 
        ELSE 
          SET cost = 1; 
        END IF; 
        SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
        IF c > c_temp THEN 
          SET c = c_temp; 
        END IF; 
        SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
        IF c > c_temp THEN 
          SET c = c_temp; 
        END IF; 
        SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
    END WHILE;
  END IF;
  RETURN c;  
END
```

Then you do need to compare all of your records to each other. This requires a self full join, which of course can be a bit heavy. If too heavy, you will need to go the Python way, which will allow you to avoid repetitions (compare various times the same records).

Here is what I would do. Note that I would rather use an ID for easier identification:

```
SELECT a.ID AS IDa,
  b.ID AS IDb,
  a.Author AS AuthorA, 
  b.Author AS AuthorB, 
  ap.levenshtein(a.Author, b.Author) AS Lev_Aut,
  a.Title AS TitleA, b.Title AS TitleB, ap.levenshtein(a.Title, b.Title) AS Lev_Title,
  a.Journal AS JounalA , b.Journal AS JournalB, ap.levenshtein(a.Journal, b.Journal) AS Lev_Journal,
  ap.levenshtein(a.Author, b.Author) + ap.levenshtein(a.Title, b.Title) + ap.levenshtein(a.Journal, b.Journal) AS Composite
FROM test.zzz AS a, test.zzz AS b 
WHERE a.ID != b.ID
ORDER BY 8;
```

Would return a list of Levenshtein values ordered from the best match to the worst (the composite column). The condition avoids a record to be compared to itself.